# Detect Design Time in JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

Is there a way to detect design time in JavaFX2 that will works in SceneBuilder? Something that similar with:

```
java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime()
```

for swing? I am developing custom control that should be displayed in SceneBuilder. However some of the codes in trigger ClassNotFoundException. I don't want to add the needed library, instead I want to bypass the code that trigger that exception.

[Update]

I'll tell what I am going to accomplish. I extends input control components (textfield, combobox etc) and add propertyName attribute. I also created a Form extends panel that will scan the input controls in it and assign value for them based on the propertName. The value is taken from the POJO that is set to the form. I use apache commons beanutls to assign the value to the input controls, thus I need to provide the classpath to the bean utils jar.

If I activate that feature automatically, I can't use Form in SceneBuilder. Because the form will detect input control in it and do the assignment thus need the library. I decided to deactivate the feature, and provide a method for programmer to activate it. It is not what I want, but I guess I have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing a design time for JavaFX controls.

Instead the control code needs to follow a couple of simple rules as outlined in this answer.

Quoting from the mailing list thread [custom controls in SceneBuilder](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/openjfx-dev/2012-August/003360.html):

> In SceneBuilder 1.0 it is not yet possible to add custom controls to
>   SceneBuilder's library panel. It is however possible to load an
>   FXML that contain custom controls. This is described in SceneBuilder's
>   User's Guide - see section on custom type elements there:
>
> http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/library-panel.htm
>
> Note that for being able to load an FXML containing a custom element
>   in SceneBuilder, that custom element must be "well behaved".
>
> 1. It must not require a special Builder Factory.
> 2. It must have a public empty constructor.
> 3. If it uses an FXMLLoader to load some nested FXML file, then that
>      FXMLLoader must be configured to use the ClassLoader from which
>      the custom component was loaded
>      (see https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?forumID=1385&threadID=2433150
>      for the gory details behind this last requirement)

To answer some additional points:

> I don't want to add the needed library, instead I want to bypass the code that trigger that exception.

The [Custom and Unknown Element Types section of the SceneBuilder User Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/user_guide/library-panel.htmZ) states that if you don't provide a path to the classes used by custom controls, the fxml will generally still load in SceneBuilder.  If a library is supplied, then SceneBuilder will provide extra functionality (Scene Builder should be able to render them in the Content panel and the Hierarchy panel).

My guess is that you will the get best support for custom controls by using a [recent 1.1+ build of SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) rather than the 1.0 release of the product.

Answer (score 0):

FXML is always design time.  If you design your control in FXML and then all the logic and event handling in it's controller then you get this for free.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this class:

```
public class SceneBuilderHelper
{
    public static boolean isSceneBuilder()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.oracle.javafx.scenebuilder.app.SceneBuilderApp");
            return true;
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
        }

        return  false;
    }
}
```

In your code you could then do this:

```
if (!SceneBuilderHelper.isSceneBuilder())
{
   // do things that should not be done in SceneBuilder
}
```